# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent, coming from middleware

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am getting this error when making a get request to a route that uses middleware. The route verifies the user has a valid token and displays a message and some basic user information.

The information is sent to the end-user just fine, however, I keep seeing these "can't set header errors" in the node console. I believe this has to do with a misusage of the next() function.

Here is my code:

**user.js (router)**

```
router.get('/me', VerifyToken, userController.me_get);
```

**VerifyToken.js (middleware)**

```
    module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    var token = req.headers['authorization'];
    //Check if token used is undefined
    if(typeof token !== 'undefined') {
        jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey', (err, authData) => {
            if(err) {
                return next(res.json({ message : 'You are not authorized to be here'}));
            } else {
                var usertoken = {
                    id : authData.user._id,
                    username : authData.user.username
                }
                res.locals.usertoken = usertoken;
                return next();
            }
          });
        return next();
    } else {
        //Forbidden
        return next(res.sendStatus(403));
    }
}
```

**users.js (controller)**

```
module.exports.me_get = (req, res, next) => {
  return res.json({ message : 'You have arrived!', usertoken : res.locals.usertoken });
}
```

I just want to get rid of that "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." in the console.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you send a response with `res.json()` (or any other method that sends the response), don't call `next()`.   `next()` will continue processing to other request handlers, some of which may try to send another response.  Since you can only send one response per request, you get the error you see.

Once you've sent the response, just return.  All processing is done at that point.

For example, replace this:

```
return next(res.json({ message : 'You are not authorized to be here'}));
```

with this:

```
res.json({ message : 'You are not authorized to be here'});
return;
```

Comment: @doobiz - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `.next` if you're ending the request. Otherwise it will go to the next middleware, which will end the request again, and you will get `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent` error, because you can't end a request twice.

Replace:

```
return next(res.sendStatus(403));
```

With

```
return res.sendStatus(403);
```

And

```
return next(res.json({ message : 'You are not authorized to be here'}));
```

With

```
return res.json({ message : 'You are not authorized to be here'});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Marcos! However, even after making those changes I still receive that error in the console.

I don't know if this matters but it does not stop my app from running.

Comment: I actually just figured it out.. I had an extra return next(); at the bottom of the if statement for the token. Rookie mistake!

The advice was still very helpful and informative

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an extra `return next()` at the bottom of my if block in the middleware.